# Using redirect_to to :create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to redirect to the create method of another controller. However, I can't find a way to set the method to POST. This results in the index method to be called. Using `:method => :post` just creates a new parameter, but doesn't change the http method.

Any ideas how to redirect to the create method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't post on a redirect. This is part of the HTTP spec - a redirect issues a http header.