# Is it bad practice to create a new record inside the new action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If, for whatever reason, I don't require a user to input data into a form to create a new record in my rails application, and instead just do this:

```
def new
  @blahblah = Blahblah.create({
    x: "blah",
    y: "blah"
  })
  redirect_to action:'index'
end
```

Would it be considered bad practice to just create the new record inside the new action like this?  I find myself often in situations where I need to save data to the database but have no need to get the data from the user via a form (sent to the create action, where I normally 'create' records).

Comment: If all `new` does is create a record and redirect, why don't you just call `create` instead?

Comment: ^^ as Logan said. That is exactly what `create` is for. `new` doesn't handle create logic. There are lots of cases where you may only need `create` and `destroy`

Comment: `redirect_to controller: 'whatever', action: 'create'` automagically takes me to whatever#index, so it seems not possible.  On the other hand, `redirect_to controller: 'whatever', action: 'new'` takes me to the new action.  So it's more of a 'I can't get to the create action so I went with the new action' issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I my view you should not make Restful dirty. You should not touch new or create action. You should go for another action in controller and do whatever you want.

This is not right way to add create code in new action. So either go to create action directly or my preferred go and make another action and put your code there.

You can create another action instead of new. So your new action won't affect.

```
##routes.tb
get 'whatever/create_record' => 'whatever#create_record', :as => 'create_record'
```

and in your controller

```
##whatever_conroller.rb
redirect_to create_record_path(:attr1 => val1 ...)
```

This will take you `create_record` method properly. And your new action won't affect. Because `new/create/update/edit/destroy` specially design for restful routing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by dirty and that I shouldn't touch these actions.  I need to use new actions to create new forms and I need to use create to create new records.  If I didn't touch them, as far as I can tell, this would be impossible.  I'll follow your advice though and try to get the code into the create action if it's possible.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to add create code in new? There must be some reason that I am missing. So I can answer you correctly.

Comment: `redirect_to controller: 'whatever', action: 'create'` automagically takes me to whatever#index.  I'm currently unable to redirect to the create action.  New seemed slightly more appropriate than index.

Comment: I just tried this and unfortunately the code was still redirected to the index action.  Rails does not seem to want me to be redirected to the create action for some reason.  I also just checked out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429755/using-redirect-to-to-create-action) and it seems to indicate that this might not be possible for some reason.

Comment: You are right. I have tried `:method => :post` in `redirect_to` and it won't work. So I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create` action. In the other hand, if you manage custom business logic you can use a custom action in your controller (don't forget to update you `routes.rb` with new action)

Answer (score 0):

> **Would it be considered bad practice**

Yes.

The entire ethos of Rails is a [`CRUD` based infrastructure](http://www.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/):

> Where would the web be with out acronyms? REST stands for
>   REpresentational State Transfer and describes resources (in our case
>   URLs) on which we can perform actions. CRUD, which stands for Create,
>   Read, Update, Delete, are the actions that we perform.
>
> Although, in
>   Rails, REST and CRUD are bestest buddies, the two can work fine on
>   their own. In fact, every time you have written a backend system that
>   allows you to add, edit and delete items from the database, and a
>   frontend that allows you to view those items, you have been working
>   with CRUD.

--

All this basically means is that when you have `controllers`, `models` and `routes`, you're working with `objects`.

Your question of:

```
def new
  @blahblah = Blahblah.create({
    x: "blah",
    y: "blah"
  })
  redirect_to action:'index'
end
```

breaks the Rails convention of CRUD. If you wanted to create an object without any input, why don't you either hard code it, or manually [`seed` it into the database](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)?

```
#app/models/blahblah.rb
class Blahblah < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.x
      # value
   end
   def self.y
     # value
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@geolocation = Geomap.x * Geomap.y
```

> where I need to save data to the database but have no need to get the
>   data from the user

What data do you need to save?

If it's stuff like `role` information, just include it in the `User` creation process, with [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) including `before_create`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create :set_role

   def set_role 
      role_id = "0" unless self.role
   end
end
```

Comment: I think my problem might be simpler than that.  I'm just unable to get to the create action.  When I try to redirect there the code automagically goes to the index action.

Comment: FYI, I have three tables in a many to many relationship almost exactly like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) except one is of populated `users` and the other is of events the users creates with a form.  The joining table is `appointments`.  I need to leave my events controller after the new event is created to go to the appointments controller to link the user with the most recently created event.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll try to figure out a way around using the new action for creating an appointment.  I'm probably doing something wrong on a more fundamental level.